# Identify this textbook

Tags: mechanical-engineering, heat-transfer, hvac, refrigeration, dehumidification

I would really like to buy this textbook, but only see a scan of one chapter online. Could anybody help me identify the book? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Searching for "*Dust particles and condensible vapors such as water vapor*" yields the rest of that chapter: https://www.caee.utexas.edu/prof/Novoselac/classes/ARE383/Handouts/Chapter%207_Thermodynamic%20Properties%20of%20Moist%20Air.pdf. Breach of copyright?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Thermal Environmental Engineering](https://www.pearson.com/us/higher-education/program/Kuehn-Thermal-Environmental-Engineering-3rd-Edition/PGM221675.html?tab=contents) 3rd Edition by Kuehn, Ramsey & Threlkeld (1998), Pearson.

[image]